# Code coverage for mocha with generators

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, generator, code-coverage, mocha.js

Since we've switched to generators I haven't been able to find a coverage tool to support this.

We use generators both in our code and in the mocha tests themselves.

We have enabled generators within the mocha tests by using co-mocha.

The only option I have in mind would be to transpile the tests instead of running them in their harmony mode.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant since node now supports generators in the default version. You can now use istanbul or any other code coverage tool you would normally use.

Answer (score 0):

[Unit-coverage](https://github.com/unit-coverage/unit-coverage) have basic harmony support.
Details [here](https://github.com/unit-coverage/unit-coverage/issues/15).

But, I can't use this tool correctly: I have error, when use `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Awhile back co-mocha worked nicely for me.  Later on in a new codebase it didn't.  After some digging I found that mocha simply isn't handling promises properly anymore and it's probably related to node 5; I've logged a [ticket](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2203).

With promise handling working properly, you theoretically shouldn't need to monkeypatch mocha to use generators.  Simply using `co.wrap()` like so should work:

```js
it('should yield in the generator', co.wrap(function*() {
   yield aPromiseReturningFunction();
   yield aGeneratorFunction();    
}));
```

In the meantime, I've written a lil utility function that wraps a generator using `co.wrap()` and passes `done` as the `then` and `catch` handlers to the promise it returns:

```js
function done(gen) {
  const wrapper = co.wrap(gen); 
  return function(done) {
    return wrapper.call(this, done).then(done).catch(done);
  };
}
```

Then I do this:

```
it('should yield in the generator', done(function*() {
   yield aPromiseReturningFunction();
   yield aGeneratorFunction();    
}));
```

Comment: The question wasn't about using mocha with generators. That part is fine and using co-mocha or co wrap should work fine. The question was about getting test coverage reports for when you use mocha with generators. 
 
Back when you had to use the --harmony flag with mocha to enable generators. The code coverage tools did not transfer this properly. This is no longer an issue since generators are part of standard node features.